# Best pattern for injecting required ngResources to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

We are using ng-resource to bring in objects from the REST endpoint.
Let's suppose we have a Category page where you can edit an Item inside that category.
When the controller requires objects (here a Category object and an Item object), we use resolvers to delay the Controller instancing before we inject those objects, based on id-s that we get from current route. Code is pretty self-explainable:

urls.js:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/categories/:categoryId/:itemId', {
    controller: 'itemController',
    resolve: Resolvers.itemController,
    templateUrl: '/templates/edit-item.html',
 })
```

item.js:

```
Resolvers.itemController = {

    item: ['$route', 'ItemResource', function ($route, ItemResource) {
        return ItemResource.get({id: $route.current.params.itemId}).$promise
    }],

    category: ['$route', 'CategoryResource', function ($route, CategoryResource) {
        return CategoryResource.get({id: $route.current.params.categoryId}).$promise
    }]

}

angular.module('controllers')
    .controller('itemController',
               ['$scope', 'item', 'category',
                function($scope, category, item) {
......
}])
```

We are facing difficulties unit-testing this controller. It means we need to inject category and item with stubs.

Is this what we are supposed to do, is it a good track? What other industry options are there that we are missing to see? Thank you!

Comment: So what difficulties do you encounter? Unit testing that controller should be easy because you can mock the dependencies..

Comment: Hi Dieter, thanks for reaching! I'm new to angular testing and I wanted to reassure myself this was the way Resolvers were meant to be used in routes, before writing lots of tests. I was thinking if injecting ItemResource/Category resource in controller and handling the promises there was more appropriate.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter that much, resolving data makes more sense if you need the data on controller initialization. All things you inject in your controller need to be mocked. The implementation of those services should be tested on their own. Hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: It does, it really does, however i put it, i need to mock the resources. *if you need the data on controller initialization* - a-ha! So that's when a resolver is required rather than preferred